# Unable to install php intl extenstion in MAC OS Ventura

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter-4, intl, macos-ventura

Iam new to Mac..

I installed Xampp 8.2.0 in php.ini I uncommented the `extension=php_intl.dll`

still not working

I am trying to install codeigniter 4 it shows Class "Locale" not found

I tried to install

pecl install intl;

> In file included from /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
> /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
> #include <unicode/ubrk.h>

Getting error like this

Please help..

Comment: Looks like you need to install some libraries befroe the compile will work

Comment: @RiggsFolly any idea which library?

Comment: I am no expert, but I would suggest Unicode

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the Xampp and I installed MAMP its working fine now... I'm Using MacBook Air M1